# Remove Line from File Based on Column Value in Perl

Tags: perl

I wish to loop through multiple files, and their respective lines in the file.  I have done is successfully already.  Want I want to do now is remove lines in a file based on a numeric value in one of the columns.

If I have an input such as this:

```
 XP.sta1    -41.5166    0.0513    0.6842    0.1794    0  CPHI.BHZ   300.2458   -42.2436
 XP.sta2      3.5972    0.0500    0.7699    0.1213    0  E000.BHZ   300.5616     2.5545
 XP.sta3      3.7112    0.0267    0.7813    0.1457    0  E002.BHZ   300.6140     2.6160
 XP.sta4      4.2891    0.0214    0.6870    0.1308    0  E004.BHZ   301.2073     2.6006
```

where the ninth column is the column I wish to look at.  I need to remove that value in column 9 (let's assign it a variable $time), in that if that $time is > 10 or less than -10, remove the entire line.  Thus far I have tried this:

```
unless (($time < -10) || ($time > 10) {     
print OUT2 ($stlat,"  ",$stlon,"  ",$eqlat,"  ",$eqlong,"  ",$eqdepth,"  ",$time,"\n");
}}
```

However I get the following output:

```
 XP.sta1    -41.5166    0.0513    0.6842    0.1794    0  CPHI.BHZ   300.2458   2.5545
 XP.sta2      3.5972    0.0500    0.7699    0.1213    0  E000.BHZ   300.5616    2.6160
 XP.sta3      3.7112    0.0267    0.7813    0.1457    0  E002.BHZ   300.6140     2.6006
 XP.sta4      4.2891    0.0214    0.6870    0.1308    0  E004.BHZ   301.2073
```

As you can see, the entire line isn't deleted -- just the value that meets the true 'unless' condition, and then the other values move up in the 9th column.  How do I delete the entire line, rather than just the ninth column number?

Here's where I wish to edit my script:

```
open(TABLEC,$File);
    @tablec = <TABLEC>;
    for ($j = 2; $j < $stop; $j++) {
       chomp ($tablec[$j]);
       ($netSta,$delayTime) = (split /\s+/,$tablec[$j])[1,9] ;  
        }
```

In this for loop, I'm looping through each file, reading in the lines from 2 to 'stop', and chopming the return character.  I set the 9th column to the delay time variable.  So I'm looping through each line, but I don't want to print anything yet (that comes later in my script).  I would just like to remove that entire line, so that later on in my script when I have to print the lines, the line where the 9th column values is >abs(10) does not exist.

Comment: We need to see the rest of your code

Comment: If the range has 0 as its midpoint then you can use `abs` (as @Borodin points out) so it could be as short as `perl -anE 'say if abs $F[8] <= 10 ;' datafile.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just skip the line:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

while(<DATA>){
    my @split = split;
    next if $split[8] > 10 or $split[8] < -10;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

---

```
 XP.sta2      3.5972    0.0500    0.7699    0.1213    0  E000.BHZ   300.5616     2.5545
 XP.sta3      3.7112    0.0267    0.7813    0.1457    0  E002.BHZ   300.6140     2.6160
 XP.sta4      4.2891    0.0214    0.6870    0.1308    0  E004.BHZ   301.2073     2.6006
```

Comment: Hi Fugu, I might have been a little too broad with my description of what I need to do.  I'd like to delete the entire line beginning with XP.sta1 (column 0) through column 8.  Then, all the lines following the line where the column 8 condition is true, just move those up.

Comment: Oh true!  I forgot about the next if operator.  I'm going to implement that operator into my script to see if I can get my desired output.  Thanks for your help fugu.

Comment: Hi fugu, I tried to implement the next if statement; however, with my edited for loop above, if I used $tablec[9], it references the ninth line instead of the ninth column.  Any ideas on how to reference the ninth column instead of the ninth line?  Thanks.

Comment: @user78872  You should ask a new question, but at a first glance your loop is not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown enough of your code to diagnose the problem, but what you ask is very simply done like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  print unless abs((split)[8]) > 10;
}

__DATA__
 XP.sta1    -41.5166    0.0513    0.6842    0.1794    0  CPHI.BHZ   300.2458   -42.2436
 XP.sta2      3.5972    0.0500    0.7699    0.1213    0  E000.BHZ   300.5616     2.5545
 XP.sta3      3.7112    0.0267    0.7813    0.1457    0  E002.BHZ   300.6140     2.6160
 XP.sta4      4.2891    0.0214    0.6870    0.1308    0  E004.BHZ   301.2073     2.6006
```

**output**

```
 XP.sta2      3.5972    0.0500    0.7699    0.1213    0  E000.BHZ   300.5616     2.5545
 XP.sta3      3.7112    0.0267    0.7813    0.1457    0  E002.BHZ   300.6140     2.6160
 XP.sta4      4.2891    0.0214    0.6870    0.1308    0  E004.BHZ   301.2073     2.6006
```

Comment: @user78872: I've seen it, but I'm not clear what your point is

Answer (score 0):

I thought your question had been answered, buit here's something that should help you with the contents of your edit

Some points on your code

- Identifiers for lexical variables should contain only lower-case letters,  decimal digits, and underscore. Capital letters are reserved for global variables such as constants and package names
- You should use *lexical file handles* with the *three-parameter* form of `open`
- You should always verify that an `open` succeeded. In the case of a failure your program should `die` and include the value of `$!` in the die string to reveal *why* the operation failed

  Together, those points mean that

  ```
  open(TABLEC, $File);
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  open my $tablec_fh, '<', $File or die qq{Unable to open "$File" for input: $!};
  ```
- You can `chomp` an entire array at once with `chomp @tablec`
- You should avoid the C-style `for` loop as it is rarely a good choice. Perl allows you to iterate over a range, and you should make use of that. So

  ```
  for ($j = 2; $j < $stop; $j++) { ... }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  for my $j ( 2 .. $stop-1 ) { ... }
  ```
- `split /\s+/` should almost always be `split ' '`. The latter is a special case for the operator, which prevents it from returning an initial empty field if the parameter string has leading spaces. If you call `split` without any parameters then it defaults to `split ' ', $_`

Here's a rewrite of your sample code that takes these points into account. I hope it's a better fit than my previous answer

```
open my $tablec_fh, '<', $File or die qq{Unable to open "$File" for input: $!};
my @tablec = <$tablec_fh>;
chomp @tablec;
close $tablec_fh;

for my $i ( 2 .. $stop-1 ) {
  my $row = $tablec[$i];
  my ($net_sta, $delay_time) = (split ' ', $row)[0,8];
  next unless abs($delay_time) <= 10;

  # Do stuff with $row
}
```